# Migrating OpenCart problems

Tags: php, migration, opencart

I just migrated my OpenCart store to a different server. I have changed the config.php files from the root and admin folders. I can access the main page and the admin back-end, but when I go to a product, it shows me a 404 file not found error.

You can take a [look at here](http://test.scienceontheweb.net/farmaciagimeno/).

What do I have to change? Is there any other config file I am missing?
thanx

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I just had to add a rewriterule to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /farmaciagimeno/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /farmaciagimeno/index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```